# User in sudo group cannot perform sudo operations

Tags: permissions, sudo

Using Ubuntu 14.04 on AWS and Ansible 1.9 and getting the following permission error:

```
$ whoami
>> ubuntu
$ mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/testfolder
>> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/testfolder’: Permission denied
$
$ # this works!!
$ sudo mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/testfolder
$ # this also works!! (maybe ubuntu doesn't have sudo privileges...)
$ sudo rm -rf $HOME/.ansible/tmp/testfolder
$
$ # ???
$ sudo adduser ubuntu sudo
>> The user `ubuntu' is already a member of `sudo'.
```

If `ubuntu` belongs to the `sudo` group, how come I can't create that directory whereas `sudo` can? How can I really give `ubuntu` the privileges of `sudo`?

**Edit**: for reference,

```
$ ls -ld /home/ubuntu/.ansible/
>> drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Sep  8 00:20 /home/ubuntu/.ansible/
```

Comment: What are you talking about? You just executed two `sudo` commands using the `ubuntu` user.

Comment: Which two commands, `mkdir` and `rm -rf`?

Comment: @muru I believe that he is trying to create a folder within a folder that he is not the owner of.  My guess is .ansible is not owned by the `ubuntu` user.

Comment: A folder that is owned by root would have to have the `sudo` command typed in to create any subfolders in it.  `sudo` is the command to run as another user with elevated permissions.  You would have to be the `root` user itself to create a folder in there without putting `sudo` in front of the command.

Comment: Thanks, @Terrance , I think so too... and my solution was to give the `ubuntu` user privileges over .ansible (is there something else I should do?)

Comment: @Terrance of course. miguel: Yes.

Comment: @miguel5 yes: `chown` those folders to `ubuntu`

Comment: @miguel5 Muru is correct.  Changing the ownership of the folder to the `ubuntu` user should be the correct procedure, as applications that are ran as a standard user need permission to the folders in the `/home/username` folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are not clear about what group `sudo` represents if a user is a member of it.

By default, if a user is a member of group `sudo`, that user can run commands as `root` by impersonating root as :

```
sudo some command
```

There is a line in the `/etc/sudoers` file that makes this possible :

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Again becomming a member of group `sudo` does not make you `root` or does not give permission to run commands only runnable by `root` on the fly. You always need to use `sudo` before that command. So if a user is not a member of group `sudo` that user won't be able to run any command as `root` even with using `sudo`.

In your case, as you were running :

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/testfolder
```

you will get permission denied message as the directory `/home/ubuntu/.ansible` is owned by `root` and there is no permission for others to write on it.

On the other hand while you were using :

```
sudo mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/testfolder
```

you were impersonating `root` who has the permission to write on that directory so the command was a success.